# Greek Characters are not displayed correctly in Sharepoint 2010 site

Tags: unicode, sharepoint-2010, utf-8, localization, internationalization

As am new in Sharepoint 2010, I have created a site and tried to import some folders from my local disk, in a library using upload document feature. Some of these folders contain greek characters in the folder name. The folders with only latin characters in folder name have been analyzed and displayed correctly after the uploading process. The problem is that the folders that contain greek characters are not analyzed at all and also the greek characters are not displayed correctly when I browse the library page in Sharepoint site.
Any assistance is kindly appreciated,
Thanks
JohnF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Copy the folders and files using [Explorer View](http://blogs.salentica.com/rvajaria/2010/05/13/where-is-explorer-view-in-sharepoint-2010/)** (*Library* tab on the ribbon / *Open with Explorer* button) - all Greek characters will be retained.

---

**Additional remark**
Problem similar to the one described in the question occurs when the folders' names contain Polish characters. Even though I am using SharePoint installation with Polish language pack, **the upload control is not localized** and I think that's the root of the problem.

[image]